# Python peek definition works in vscode, but pylint complains about being unable to import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I want to test some python files in a project before installing them. For this I entered the folder to be installed in my vscode workspace settings as follows:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/lib_python/release"
]
```

Now I have a test file in my workspace that imports from the above mentioned folder. Suggestions work fine, it also gives me definitions while hovering with the mouse over a class name from the imported file. However, half my code is underlined in red, because pylint says it does not know the definitions and cannot import.

**Question:** Is there a way to also make whatever part of the python plugin by `Don Jayamanne` is responsible for the red underlining find the additional import folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what worked for me now is to set additional paths in a `.env` file in the project's root folder. This file will be read by the python extension of vscode.

Example:

```
PYTHONPATH=./lib_python/release
```

Answer (score 0):

In User Settings -> Extensions be sure `python` command is the right one. On my Mac, `python` refers to Python 2.x, however `python3` refers to Python 3.X. I simply changed VSCode's `python` command to `python3` and this resolved my issue.